# Unable to use Ansible `copy` operation to EC2 host via bastion

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ansible, bastion-host

I am trying to set up an EC2 instance VM on AWS behind a bastion. Ansible performance is very slow but bearable for most operations but file copy operations simply hang and I can't really see what the issue is. The role and playbook work fine connected to a public facing EC2 instance. The copy stanza is:

```
- name: Copy all files from local dir to remote dir
copy:
    src: files/files_to_host/
    dest: /home/ec2-user
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user
    mode: 0644
```

There are 22 files totalling 22MB with some subdirectories in the `src` location. I've tried the following `ansible.cfg` based on [Jeff Geerling's post](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2022/using-ansible-playbook-ssh-bastion-jump-host) and [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798774/how-to-detect-why-ansible-playbook-hangs-during-execution) but it hasn't helped (tried with various lines commented/uncommented):

```
[ssh_connection]
scp_if_ssh = true
; ssh_args = -o ServerAliveInterval=30

ansible_ssh_common_args='-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q myuser@bastion"'
```

and with it when I run

```
ansible-playbook -vvvv -i 10.0.129.157, -u ec2-user my-playbook.yml
```

I get the following error (formatted for legibility):

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /Users/myuser/ansible/my-playbook.yml:5
<10.0.129.157> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ec2-user
<10.0.129.157> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ec2-user"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath="/Users/myuser/.ansible/cp/0cdf5a0bfd"' 10.0.129.157 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ec2-user && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.0.129.157> (255, b'', b'OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.5
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/myuser/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.0.129.157 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile \'~/.ssh/known_hosts\' -> \'/Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts\'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile \'~/.ssh/known_hosts2\' -> \'/Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts2\'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: Control socket "/Users/myuser/.ansible/cp/0cdf5a0bfd" does not exist
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.129.157 [10.0.129.157] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: connect to address 10.0.129.157 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 10.0.129.157 port 22: Operation timed out
')
fatal: [10.0.129.157]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.5
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/myuser/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.0.129.157 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: Control socket \"/Users/myuser/.ansible/cp/0cdf5a0bfd\" does not exist
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.129.157 [10.0.129.157] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: connect to address 10.0.129.157 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 10.0.129.157 port 22: Operation timed out",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

If I use sshuttle as recommended at https://blog.keyboardinterrupt.com/ansible-jumphost/ to open a tunnel to the bastion I can perform remote operations ok, but file copy from local to remote gives errors like

```
<10.0.129.157> (0, b'/home/ec2-user\n', b"OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.5
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/myuser/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.0.129.157 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4
debug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote
debug3: mux_client_request_session: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 17624
debug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2
debug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe
debug2: Received exit status from master 0
")
```

I am able to use `ssh -J` and `sftp -J` successfully and speedily and I am able to access remote host via ssh over sshuttle. I have already added these two lines to the bastion `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
MaxStartups 50:30:80
MaxSessions 50
```

What do I need to do to get Ansible to work correctly via bastion?

Comment: It seems you have confused the `ansible.cfg` ini key with the `vars:` key; [the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/5/collections/ansible/builtin/ssh_connection.html#parameter-ssh_common_args) lays it out in detail, showing the ini flavor and the variable flavor, so pick one or the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I still don't really know why my previous attempts partially worked rather than completely failing or completely succeeding, I have found a solution that I am pleased with that does not require a central static config file (i.e. no `ansible.cfg` or `ini` file at all) or any additional utilities:

```sh
ansible-playbook -i 10.0.130.90, -u ec2-user myplaybook.yml --ssh-common-args "-J myuser@bastion"
```

This presumes ssh-keys for both hosts are added to ssh, e.g. with `ssh-add`